# en.yml changes not taking effect

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, syntax, yaml

I've made some changes to the en.yml and it's still showing the old error message I previously made.

```
en:  
  activerecord:
    models: 
      packjob: 
    attributes:
        pj_packer: 
    errors:
      models:
        packjob:
          attributes:
            pj_packer:
            blank: "A packer must be selected"
```

I've recycled the rails server and it's still showing the old error message:

```
Pj packer can't be blank
```

Why is the old error message still being picked up instead of the new one?

Comment: Looks like you're missing indentation for `blank`.

Comment: Yup that seemed to resolve the problem...thanks!

Comment: To extend this...how do I change it to say: "Packer: A packer must be selected"....not the name of the column "Pj packer" ?

Comment: For your other question, without knowing how you're outputting messages in your code, I think it's a matter of giving your `pj_packer` attribute a string ie `pj_packer: "Packer"` under `activerecord, models, packjob, attributes`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing indentation for `blank`.